# Shared Preference not changing value immediately?

Tags: java, android

I have a `GridView` and each item is a set that opens an activity but first it checks if this item is unlocked or not by using a `boolean` that it's value is saved by a `SharedPreference` and if it's locked it changes a `String` named `name` to the item name and opens an `AlertDialog`  and if the user press the positive button it should change the value of the `boolean` to false which means it's no longer locked and it should open normally but the problem is that is doesn't change the user has to unlock it twice for it to change and I checked if everything is going right using `Log` and everything is going right except for the boolean value is not changing, can someone tell how to fix this.

Here is my code:

this is my `onCreate` method:

```
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    final SharedPreferences shared = getSharedPreferences("PrefName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shared.edit();
    final int Coins = shared.getInt("CoinsValue", 1000);
    final boolean game = (shared.getBoolean("game", true));

    // 1. Instantiate an AlertDialog.Builder with its constructor
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainMenu.this);

    // 2. Chain together various setter methods to set the dialog characteristics
    builder.setMessage("Unlock a new set to have more fun")
            .setTitle("UNLOCK SET");

    // Add the buttons
    builder.setPositiveButton("100 coins", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            if (Coins >= 100){
                editor.putInt(name, false).apply();
                Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Set Unlocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                coinsValue = Coins - 100;
                editor.putInt("CoinsValue", coinsValue);
                editor.apply();
                Log.e("Msg", "" + name + " value = " + deathparade);
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // User cancelled the dialog
        }
    });

    // 3. Get the AlertDialog from create()
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position){
                case 9:
                    Log.e("Msg", "Game value = " + game);
                    if(game){
                        name = "game";
                        editor.putString("nameLock", "game");
                        editor.apply();
                        Log.e("Msg", "" + name);
                        dialog.show();
                    } else {
                        editor.putInt("ArrayValue", R.array.game);
                        editor.putInt("DrawableValue", R.drawable.game_bg);
                        editor.apply();
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainMenu.this, MainActivity.class));
                    }
                    break;
```

Comment: Does it work if you use `commit` instead of `apply`?

Comment: @OskarKjellin no it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

using `apply()` does not save it immediately. if you need to save it immediately you should use `commit` but using commit could block the ui thread.

Note:

if you use `commit` you get this warning which tells you the differences

`Consider using apply() instead; commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background`

Comment: shouldnt you be checking if `game` is `true/false` and not an int value?

Comment: sorry that was a typing error, I fixed it that is the correct code